# Drools updating same object at the same time

Tags: drools

I have two .drl files:

**.dlr file one**

```
rule "Lower Elementary Level"
    no-loop

    when
        $m: MockBean ( overAllScore >= 40.51 && overAllScore < 60.76 )
        $s : StudentMockBean()
    then
        $s.setKnowledgeLevel( "Lower Elementary Level" );
        update( $s );
end

// some other condition
```

**.drl file two**

```
rule "Concept Lower Elementary Level"
    no-loop

    when
        $m: MockBean ( mockOneScore >= 40.51 && mockOneScore < 60.76 )
        $s : StudentMockBean()
    then
        $s.setMockOneKnowledgeLevel( "Lower Elementary Level" );
        update( $s );
end

// some other condition
```

I'm reading both of them through this:

```
...
for( String fileName : aRuleFileName )
{
     kbuilder.add( ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource( fileName, getClass() ), ResourceType.DRL );
}

// get error

KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
kbase.addKnowledgePackages( kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages() );

return kbase;
```

I fired both rules and both **.drl** file met the condition but they are updating same object.

**My question is why does my web app keep on loading infinitely?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having an infinite loop caused by the combination of your rules.
I.e. `rule A activates -> rule A fires -> modifies $s -> rule B activates -> rule B fires -> modifies $s -> rule A activates -> rule A fires -> modifies $s -> rule B activates -> rule B fires -> ...`

`no-loop` is not enough solution for this situation. 
For a better explanation on what's going on and possible ways to solve your problem please read [this blog entry](http://ilesteban.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/about-drools-and-infinite-execution-loops/).

Hope it helps,